# Website background Image height scrolling problem

Tags: html, css, image, web-frontend

I have a big "img" background image that is put inside the "Figure" tag as the main background of the site. I set the max-width to 100% and the height to 100% too.

When I start scrolling from the top of my page to the bottom.

As soon as I reach the beginning/top of an image, the scroll stops, then I need to scroll again to reach the bottom of the page. Same as when I scroll from bottom to up. This problem is happening on the touchpad scroll and the keyboard up and down arrows.

I noticed that whether scrolling from top to bottom or bottom to up of the image, the vertical scroll bar doesn't move; it starts moving when I have to scroll again up or down of the site.

However, the following steps are done.

1. The scrolling worked smoothly when I reduced the "Height" of the img exactly below "86%" in the CSS file. However, "86% - 100%" the problem starts there.
2. I tried to use the "img" tag, then I replaced it with the "Background-Image: url()" property. Same problem with step one.
3. I tried to reduce (compress) the image size. Same problem with step one.
4. I used the "Background-size" with the different values (contain, cover, auto). Same problem with step one.
5. I used "Background-Attachment: Scroll;" the Same problem as step one.

> Updated: I added "P" with a lot of lorem text under the image so that I can scroll enough. The scrolling problem was solved even though the height of the image is "Height: 100%", whether it's "img tag" or "Background-Image: url()"

**Thus, the main problem is with the height, but I need the image to be "100%" not below "86%".**

Any suggestions, please?

```
<body>
        --Hidden Content--
 
        <!------------------
        ----MAIN CONTENT----
        -------------------->
        <main>
            <section class="upperpart">

                <header class="main_header">
                    <div class="getoff">
                       <h2>get rm10 off</h2>
                        <p>your first order
                            <span>code:shemya</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="share">
                        <h2>share & earn</h2>
                        <p>up to 15% off</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                       
                        <h2>cash on delivery</h2>

                    </div>
                </header>

                <figure class="main_figure">
                    <img src="https://www.lux-review.com/wp- 
                      content/uploads/2022/05/Kids-Fashion.jpg" alt=""
                        height="85%">
                    <figcaption></figcaption>

                    <img src="" alt="">

                    <div class="figure_ads">
                        <p>mega year end sale now on</p>
                        <p>up to <span>80%</span>off</p>
                        <button>buy now</button>
                    </div>
                </figure>

            <section class="middelpart">
                 --Hidden Content--
            </section>
            
           <section class="bottompart">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
                   elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non
                    amet
                    .</p>
            </section>
        </main>
```

```css
main {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 15.2rem;
}

main .upperpart {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 80rem;
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* visibility: hidden; */
   
}

.upperpart .main_figure {
    width: 90vw;
    /* max-height: 60rem; */
    position: relative;
   
}

.upperpart .main_figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

main .bottompart p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
   
}
```

Comment: can you put some code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, I don't really see where is the problem.

The only thing I've found is the section upperpart is not close before the main closure.

```css
main {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 15.2rem;
}

main .upperpart {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 80rem;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
}

.upperpart .main_figure {
  width: 90vw;
  /* max-height: 60rem; */
  position: relative;
}

.upperpart .main_figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main .bottompart p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="upperpart">

    <header class="main_header">
      <div class="getoff">
        <h2>get rm10 off</h2>
        <p>your first order
          <span>code:shemya</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="share">
        <h2>share & earn</h2>
        <p>up to 15% off</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>cash on delivery</h2>
      </div>
    </header>

    <figure class="main_figure">
      <img src="https://www.lux-review.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Kids-Fashion.jpg" alt="" height="85%">
      <figcaption></figcaption>

      <img src="" alt="">

      <div class="figure_ads">
        <p>mega year end sale now on</p>
        <p>up to <span>80%</span>off</p>
        <button>buy now</button>
      </div>
    </figure>

    <section class="middelpart">
      --Hidden Content--
    </section>

    <section class="bottompart">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit fugit earum accusantium non amet.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

I don't have scrolling trouble on this snippet. Do you have?